# How can I get the contents of a variable up to the first new line?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in Javascript that can contain a message with one or more `\n` line breaks:

```
var a = multiLine;
```

How can I make it so that the variable `a` only contains the first line of the contents of the 
`multiLine` variable?

Comment: Do oyu know what the break looks like?  Is it <br/> or \n or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually break line symbol is `'\n'`

```
var lines = a.split('\n');
var firstLine = lines[0];
```

or in one piece of code

```
var firstLine = a.split('\n')[0];
```

or whatever the break line symbol is in your case you can substitude it in the `split` methhod.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()` e.g.

```
var a = multiline.substring(0, multiline.indexOf('\n'));
```